# How to install zipline module in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, zipline

I am using pycharm as my IDE, I found problem to install zipline to pycharm. I have tried the method by pip install zipline, but it is not working.

Are there any parts I missed or any guide to deal with it?

Comment: What was the issue with installing via pip?

Comment: the terminal pass an result of 
Successfully installed Logbook-1.0.0 Mako-1.0.6 alembic-0.8.10 bcolz-0.12.1 cachetools-2.0.0 cyordereddict-1.0.0 empyrical-0.2.2 intervaltree-2.1.0 pandas-0.17.1 pandas-datareader-0.3.0.post0 python-editor-1.0.3 requests-file-1.4.1 requests-ftp-0.3.1 sortedcontainers-1.5.7 zipline-1.0.2

It cause error while I type 
import zipline

Comment: Are you sure that your terminal is using the same interpreter as PyCharm? Try going to Settings (or Preferences), then choosing Project -> Project Interpreter. See if zipline is listed in the installed packages. If not, use PyCharm's UI (the + sign) to add zipline from inside PyCharm.

Comment: My zipline was not in the list, when I imstall in the PyCharm's UI, the PyCharm have an errors 
Collecting zipline
  Using cached zipline-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jh/m1gpqh3n7fqby5hgpv04f6rr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/zipline/setup.py", line 277, in <module>
        packages=find_packages(include=['zipline', 'zipline.*']),
    TypeError: find_packages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42942391/5687225) by MikeyE didn't work for me since I didn't have zipline listed there -- what worked for me instead was

`conda install -c Quantopian zipline`

Comment: What do you mean when you say you didn't have zipline listed?

Answer (score 1):

To start, in PyCharm open `Settings -> Project(XXX) -> Project Interpreter`. Then click on the `+` icon in the top right of the screen, type `Zipline` in the search bar, then click on `Install Package` to install Zipline.

You'll need to download the sample Quandl data, by running this on the command line:

```
zipline ingest -b quantopian-quandl
```

To test if Zipline was installed successfully, create 'dual_moving_average.py' and paste in this sample application:

```
from zipline.api import (
history,
order_target,
record,
symbol,
)

def initialize(context):
    context.i = 0

def handle_data(context, data):
    # Skip first 300 days to get full windows
    context.i += 1
    if context.i < 300:
        return

    # Compute averages
    # history() has to be called with the same params
    # from above and returns a pandas dataframe.
    short_mavg = history(100, '1d', 'price').mean()
    long_mavg = history(300, '1d', 'price').mean()

    sym = symbol('AAPL')

    # Trading logic
    if short_mavg[sym] > long_mavg[sym]:
        # order_target orders as many shares as needed to
        # achieve the desired number of shares.
        order_target(sym, 100)
    elif short_mavg[sym] < long_mavg[sym]:
        order_target(sym, 0)

    # Save values for later inspection
    record(AAPL=data[sym].price,
           short_mavg=short_mavg[sym],
           long_mavg=long_mavg[sym])
```

To run the algo using Zipline, execute the following on the command line (you can change the dates to a time-frame more to your liking of course):

```
zipline run -f dual_moving_average.py --start 2011-1-1 --end 2012-1-1 -o dma.pickle
```

If all this works without error, do a little happy dance! :-) Because, Zipline is now installed, and you've run your first algo.

Comment: Beginner question. Are you somehow using the command line syntax to invoke the algorithm from within PyCharm ???

Comment: @JohnStrong Yes, what I do is right-click the `dual_moving_average.py` file I want to run, then click `Run`.  That usually fails, but then I edit the run-configuration in PyCharm, change the `Script Path` to the zipline executable, and add whatever arguments I need in the `Parameters` field.  Once configure, you can run it from the tool-bar or by mapping a hot-key.

Comment: Are you unable to dispense with the tweaks to Script Path and just invoke the algorithm with `run_algorithm()`?

Comment: @JohnStrong It's been a while since I've tried, but if I remember correctly I had some problems using `run_algorithm()` directly in PyCharm.  It's possible the folks working on Zipline might have made some improvements since then, but I haven't tried it.  The only was I was able to get it working was using the `zipline run...` command I noted in my answer above.